# How to Wire a Brushless Motor with 8 stators?

Tags: motors

I am currently for the past few years creating a Brushless Motor on and off. The stator I have built has 8 Stators and I cannot seem to find out how to wire this. I see most Brushless Motors with 9 Stators. Is this possible and if so how would I be able to get this working? If you do know how to wire this can you please provide a small diagram on wiring this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you mean you have built a motor with eight **poles** on one stator.  The reason that brushless motors generally have some multiple of three poles on the stator is because they are three phase.  If you want to carry on with your 8-pole stator, you need to wind it as a 2- 4- or 8-phase motor -- and then you need to design and build a driver that can handle that.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean thanks for clearing it up. So your saying I would either have to make a new one, or use the 2-4-8 Phase motor, which I will have to lookup to see what it is. The driver you are talking about is the pole in the middle?

Comment: I mean a 2-phase motor or a 4-phase motor or an 8-phase motor.  And the driver I'm talking about is the electronics.

Comment: Oh okay. So when I’m winding the poles I would have to wind like pole A1 to pole A2 on opposite sides? And so on, until I go to D1 and D2? Then the loose copper wiring will go to the driver?

Comment: Yes.  It will go to the driver that you do not have, that nobody makes, and for which there are no DIY articles on the web.

Comment: Wow, I'll have to try to make it. Thanks for giving me the information I need.

Comment: It may be a lot less effort to make yourself a 6- or 9-pole stator, and a rotor to match.